# PHP renaming array and covert from string to integer

Tags: php, arrays, string, int, renaming

I have var_dump() variable $fruit_array as below:

```
array (size=3)
  0 => 
    array (size=1)
      'fruit_id' => string '2' (length=1)
  1 => 
    array (size=1)
      'fruit_id' => string '1' (length=1)
  2 => 
    array (size=1)
      'fruit_id' => string '3' (length=1)
```

I need to rename `fruit_id` to `id` and convert array `string` value to `integer`, example result:

```
array (size=3)
  0 => 
    array (size=1)
      'id' => int 2
  1 => 
    array (size=1)
      'id' => int 1
  2 => 
    array (size=1)
      'id' => int 3
```

How can I do that ? thanks

Comment: you can't rename array keys. but you can create a new one, copy/change the value, then delete the original.

Comment: any reason why I can't rename array keys?

Comment: ask the php designers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
<?php
foreach ( $array as $k=>$v )
{
  $array[$k] ['id'] = intval( $array[$k] ['fruit_id'] );
  unset($array[$k]['fruit_id']);
}
```

Comment: thank you, this is what I need :), can you show another method using array_map() ?